# In Z3, how to access sample assignment in satisfiable "exists" query?

Tags: z3

I have a simple Z3 "exists" query that is clearly satisfiable.

```
(assert
  (forall ((a Real) (c Real))
      (exists ((b Real))
        (=>
          (= a c)
          (and (= b a) (= b c))
        )
       )
   )
)
(check-sat)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way in Z3 to access the value of `a` that proves this query is satisfiable, i.e. `a = b` or `a = c`.

EDIT: If this is not possible, is it instead possible to see a proof that the query is satisfiable?

Comment: SMT solvers only provide "concrete" models; i.e., only constant values. You are asking for a "symbolic" value in your model, which is beyond the scope of what an SMT solver can do.

Comment: I see. Even so, Z3 must have some reason to conclude satisfiability. Is it possible to see its proof? I've edited my question to include this.

Comment: You can get a proof with the command `(get-proof)` only if the SMT solver concluded `unsat`. (No proofs will be given for `sat` responses.) You can assert the negation of your property and ask for a proof, but what you'll get will probably not be interesting by any means.